# Autohotkey and Logi MX Master 3 on windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

this is what I'm trying to achieve using autohotkey:

I want my keyboard buttons to be from:
Ctrl + Win + Alt
to
Win + Alt + Ctrl

And I can easily do that with autohotkey, but there is a problem: swithching between desktops. I would like to switch between desktops using LWin (which is now on the ctrl key) + left/right arrow key, the problem is that if I go to the logi option app and I set a shortcut the app recognize badly the keys, so actually I'm unable to switch between desktops using my mouse. Plus I would like to have ctrl (which is alt key) + tab to behave like alt tab.

Also, there are other features that I'm using on autohotkey that I would like to keep using, here is the script I'm using:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
RAlt::LAlt
^Space::Send, {Ctrl up}{LWin}
^Q::Send !{F4}
RCtrl::RAlt
```

How can I improve this to achieve my needs? Thanks. Hope I explained myself well.

Comment: I recommend [VD.ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=83381&p=365265&hilit=Desktops#p365035). Then you don't have to use the standard Win10 hotkeys to switch between desktops and offers a lot of other features.

Answer (score 0):

The Logitech Options software uses direct hardware input as far as I know, so Autohotkey does not work here.

However, you can use desktop control in Logitech Options with the MX Master via gesture control.

Comment: I already tried it, that function simply uses system shortcuts, hence using autohotkey to swap the keys will produce a non working result.

Comment: Autohotkey will probably work on no periphery focused tool because tools like logitech options or others will mostly use the direct hardware input and ignore every software controled changes.

There is no option to change system hotkeys in windows 10, but you could try to use an autoit script to perform such actions. You should be able to execute these scripts with using an hotkey and calling them from logitech options.